# unknown file 663.php in ftp root

Tags: ftp

For some reasons I have a `663.php` file in every folder and subfolders of my httpdoc root in my web server ftp. I don't know where this file came from and my host does not know either
I would very much appreciate any help

Comment: Is it empty, or is there content in it?

Comment: it actually has a code inside

Comment: wishlistvu5.php
unevaluated.html
postponed.html
measure.php
captive.html
these are also unknown files and the .htaccess has been modified too

Comment: Could you zip the file an upload it? I'll look at it. It is very likely a sign that your site has been hacked. And someone is using it to send spam e-mails.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. After a little search i found out that It was a Plesk security vulnerability. The problem was solved by running a patch in parallels plesk. Apart from inserting unknown files it also changed .htaccess to redirect to weird websites.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on it's content it could seem like a PHP Shell Backdoor.

An attacker would upload this file to gain access to your files, database ect.
They usually exploit a flaw in your application, to upload files.

Be sure to update all the software you are running.

Someone might have gained access to your site, also change all passwords.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. After a little search i found out that It was a Plesk security vulnerability. The problem was solved by running a patch in parallels plesk. Apart from inserting unknown files it also changed .htaccess to redirect to weird websites.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this has occurred before to other users:

> Your site has been hacked.  The 663.php file is sending out anonymous
>   spam.  If you host with GoDaddy, this is a common theme as thousands
>   of accounts share one IP  and one person with shell access can get in
>   and place an htaccess file above the root folder on the server and
>   autoload the files into every folder in your website and onto every
>   site within that IP address.  Year1Media

Quote from [AolAnswers](http://aolanswers.com/questions/663-php-root-file_273993898110815?#answers).

Comment: wishlistvu5.php unevaluated.html postponed.html measure.php captive.html these are also unknown files and the .htaccess has been modified too

Answer (score -1):

It Is a Plesk Problem
they are correction patches here:

http://kb.parallels.com/en/113321